# Set up mocha to run different folder tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a folder structure as follow:

[image]

The package.json has the following configuration:

```
{
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./**/*-tests.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "should": "^13.2.3",
    "should-sinon": "0.0.6",
    "sinon": "^9.0.1"
}
```

}

Now from the command line I can execute *"npm test"* and all tests, integration and unit, will run.

I would like to be able to pass a parameter, something like *"npm test --folder unit_tests"*, so only one set of tests under the same folder will run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define separate test-`scripts` for integration and unit tests in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test:unit": "mocha path/to/unit-test-folder/*-tests.js",
    "test:integration": "mocha path/to/integration-test-folder/*-tests.js"
}
```

You can then call them independently as:

```
npm run test:unit
npm run test:integration
```